# Why is there a high value resistor between source and gate in this p channel mosfet?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistors

I am trying to understand practical uses of mosfets and came across the circuit from the image below. The PWREN1# is active low,and comes from a IC that is being powered by VCC5V also.

So I know a p channel mosfet is active when then difference between the voltage of source and gate are negative, so I understand why the circuit uses the pwren#1 as gate, but I can't understand why the R7 resistor is needed there, connecting the source to gate.

Sorry if this a common circuit knowledge or a easy problem, but I am still a newbie when dealing with real practical circuits, and not ones made to just test if I know how to use the right equation.

[image]

Comment: It is believed (this site including) that R2/R7 resistors and C13 capacitor control inrush current if the circuit load (not shown here) is capacitive with a large capacitance value. To understand their effect, simulate this circuit with and without R7 (possibly changing R2 values) for all possible scenarios with abrupt switching on/off of VCC5V and PWREN1$ and a load in the range of 10uF and greater. Measure the current through the load. Also, R7 value is unnecessarily high: in a practical design this would be on the order of 100K, with R2 resistance and C13 capacitance changed accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

R7 is probably there to ensure that the MOSFET is off when there is nothing driving the input PWREN1#.

That could be because it is driven from an open-drain output, for example from a microprocessor. When the microprocessor is first powered up the outputs are usually high-impedance, if R7 was not present the voltage at its gate would be indeterminate and could incorrectly turn on the output.

Another reason you may see similar arrangement is where the supply rail is more than 10-12V. The maximum gate voltage is in the range of 8-20V and with a higher voltage supply it would be possible to exceed that, the potential divider formed by R12 and R7 reduces the voltage to something that the MOSFET can handle. That is not required in this example as the supply is only 5V and it would actually be better to put R7 at the input side of R12 to ensure there is adequate drive for the MOSFET.

Comment: R12 isn't helping matters though, as it's reducing Vgs to only 4.16V instead of the full swing of 5V., Maybe the FET is replacing a PNP?

Comment: @hacktastical - I agree that it would be better to put R7 at the input than after R12 in this example.

Comment: "incorrectly turn on the output." Or worse, turn the output halfway on, or on and off 50x per second by picking up mains hum...

Comment: @user_1818839 - true.

Comment: so instead of staying the way it is, connect in series with r12?

Comment: @GustavoRodriguesSartori - no. Connect R7 between PWREN1# and VCC5V (ie use the other end of R12). That would avoid the reduction in drive voltage that hacktastical commented on.